# JQuery Live() not working

Tags: asp.net, jquery, live

I have made an custom collapsible fieldset control in asp.net. I use jquery to add the toggle effects. The control works perfectly but when i am using my fieldsets inside an updatepanel, afer a postback i loose my jquery logic because of the document.ready.

Now i have read about the new Live() function of Jquery but i don't get it working. What do i do wrong? Has someone the answer??

Thanks a lot

My Jquery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.fn.collapse = function(options) {
        var defaults = { closed: false }
        settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() {
            var obj = $(this);

            obj.find("legend").addClass('SmartFieldSetCollapsible').live("click", function() {


                if (obj.hasClass('collapsed')) { 
                obj.removeClass('collapsed').addClass('SmartFieldSetCollapsible'); }

                $(this).removeClass('collapsed');

                obj.children().next().toggle("slow", function() {

                    if ($(this).is(":visible")) {

                        obj.find("legend").addClass('SmartFieldSetCollapsible');
                        obj.removeAttr("style");
                        obj.css({ padding: '10px' });
                        obj.find(".imgCollapse").css({ display: 'none' });
                        obj.find(".imgExpand").css({ display: 'inline' });

                    }
                    else {

                        obj.css({ borderLeftColor: 'transparent', borderRightColor: 'transparent', borderBottomColor: 'transparent', borderWidth: '1px 0px 0px 0px', paddingBottom: '0px' });
                        obj.find(".imgExpand").css({ display: 'none' });
                        obj.find(".imgCollapse").css({ display: 'inline' });

                    }
                });
            });

            if (settings.closed) {
                obj.addClass('collapsed').find("legend").addClass('collapsed');
                obj.children().filter("p,img,table,ul,div,span,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5").css('display', 'none');
            }
        });
    };


});


$(document).ready(function() {

$("fieldset.SmartFieldSetCollapsible").collapse();

});
```

Comment: +1 I like the idea of using the arrow (collapsed/expanded) totally CSS via the border width

Comment: are you sure live() is even called?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are doing more then just a plain selector for your live selection

From [api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/live/)
"DOM traversal methods are not fully supported for finding elements to send to .live(). Rather, the .live() method should always be called directly after a selecton"

Comment: +1 Thanks, I always had problems with the `live()` method, that s a good thing to know!

Comment: It makes sense if you think about it... `live` is supposed to check whether target elements match a particular selector at event time, not at call time. A `$()` wrapper at heart represents a list of elements matched at the time it was created; it's a total hack that you can call `live()` on it to repurpose the selector it was created with. This is bad, misleading API design! It should have been called `$.live(selector, eventType, handler)`.

Comment: This was exactly my problem, Thanks Petersen. Cached selectors, while normally preferable because you don't have to query the dom again, give .live() trouble. Don't do this like I did, it won't work:  
$("dd", this._$element).live("click", function (event) {});

Answer (score 2):

```
            if (obj.hasClass('collapsed')) { 
            obj.removeClass('collapsed').addClass('SmartFieldSetCollapsible'); }

            $(this).removeClass('collapsed');
```

First you want to remove the class an add another class if it has the class collapsed, an then you remove the class collapsed. I don't know if it affects the working of the system but it is worth to try.

Does the function work if you just use .click (when the field aren't updated)?

Comment: Hi all,
The live( doesn't get called. So this woun't work. I have solved this issue by using a hidden field. In this field i keep track of which fielset is open or closed. So now everything works fine. So thank u all for your replay's

Greatings Talsja

Answer (score 1):

Traversing is the issue. You can solve it with a simple selection.

```
var obj = $(this),
    obj.find("legend").addClass('SmartFieldSetCollapsible');
$('legend.SmartFieldSetCollapsible').live('click.collapsible', function(e){
```